# How to subtract two sparsevector?

Tags: java, vector, colt

I'm new to dealing with `SparseVector`. I want to subtract two `SparseVectors` and return result as `SparseVector` too.

What is the difference between `Vector` and `SparseVector`?

I tried to start with define function that take two `SparseVector` but didn't get antything that helped me!

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashMap;
import cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList;
import cern.colt.matrix.impl.SparseDoubleMatrix1D;

public class SparseVector extends SparseDoubleMatrix1D {
    public SparseVector(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    public SparseVector(double[] values) {
        super(values);
    }

    public  SparseVector subtract(SparseVector v1, SparseVector v2) {
        // TODO: How to implement it?
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the current implementation of the `SparseVector` class? Could you please point out what is the expected semantics of the `subtract()` method?

Comment: i defined method subtract to make me call it in another class that will take two sparse vector to return result in one sparsevector

Comment: Should the method be `static`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no need to create a custom implementation. Please consider the following example:

```
import cern.colt.matrix.impl.SparseDoubleMatrix1D;
import cern.jet.math.Functions;

// …

final SparseDoubleMatrix1D aMatrix = new SparseDoubleMatrix1D(new double[] { 3.0 });
final SparseDoubleMatrix1D bMatrix = new SparseDoubleMatrix1D(new double[] { 1.0 });
aMatrix.assign(bMatrix, Functions.minus);
// aMatrix is the result.
System.out.println(aMatrix);
```

Please refer to the [cern.jet.math.Functions class](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/jet/math/Functions.html).

## Custom implementation

Note that the static method may be redundant.

```
import cern.colt.matrix.impl.SparseDoubleMatrix1D;
import cern.jet.math.Functions;

final class SparseVector extends SparseDoubleMatrix1D {
    public SparseVector(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    public SparseVector(double[] values) {
        super(values);
    }

    /**
     * Subtract otherVector from this vector.
     * The result is stored in this vector.
     * @param otherVector other vector
     * @return this vector
     */
    public SparseVector subtract(SparseVector otherVector) {
        assign(otherVector, Functions.minus);
        return this;
    }

    public static SparseVector subtract(SparseVector x, SparseVector y) {
        final SparseVector result = new SparseVector(x.toArray());
        result.subtract(y);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
final SparseVector aVector = new SparseVector(new double[] { 3.0 });
final SparseVector bVector = new SparseVector(new double[] { 1.0 });

aVector.subtract(bVector);

// aVector is the result.
System.out.println(aVector);
```

Comment: thanks but i need it in a method , as i said i have two sparse vector in another class have values and i need to subtract them